# SQL doesn't accept my minimum date from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I use the layer2 cloud connector to sync between Sharepoint DB (right) and SQL Server database (left). I sync from right to left only.
I make a dynamic column on the right side, which has the following code:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(NächstesFSKontrolldatum.ToString())) 
{  
    return DateTime.Parse("1753-01-01T00:00:00.000"); 
} 
else 
{ 
    return NächstesFSKontrolldatum; 
}
```

In the first part I try to return the minimum SQL Server `datetime` value, which our system needs instead of null.

But I get the following error:

> The provider 'System.Data.SqlClient' marked the row 'xyz' as erroneous: SqlDateTime-Überlauf; muss zwischen 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM und 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM liegen.

Which means in English there is an overflow, because it is out of the range.

I tried to use

```
DateTime sqlMinDateAsNetDateTime = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value;
```

and return that, but the namespace `Data` isn't known in my program's environment.

How to pass the value correctly to write the real minimum date?

Comment: tried that: return new DateTime(1753,1,1,0,0,0); but no

Comment: Check database definition for the column using SQL Server Management Studio.  There is more than one type of Date.  Some date types only go to 1900 while other go to 1/1/1.

Comment: Have you tried making sure it is a UTC date? The SQL min date is indeed 1 Jan 1753, but if you're not using UTC, the local time could be a few hours below that. Maybe try `new DateTime(1753,1,1,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc)`

Comment: thanks tried ´new DateTime(1,1,1753,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc)#´ and ´new DateTime(1753,1,1,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc)´ but the same error

Comment: The actual problem aside, imho you shouldn't store unknown dates as some (min) datetime - i'd store them as `NULL`.

Comment: I'd as well but I use a solution with Navision which is already built. Have no influence on that.

Comment: tried `return DateTime.Parse("1753-01-01")` but no

Comment: Still could be it expects *greater 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM* rather than *greater-or-equal 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM*. I'd give noon a shot: `DateTime(1753,1,1,12,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc)`.

Comment: Good idea, but I already read the data out and it was midnight. Also on the left-to-right sync the following comparison works fine: `DL_Checking_Date == DateTime.Parse("01.01.1753")`.
I will try it out later anyway, but for now I don't want to change all the dates on the sql side to that value because I can't access the sql server directly to edit them back.

Comment: I think when you are parsing the dates it is trying to convert this into utc and then it is converting it to 1752. can you confirm this?  and per this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.minvalue?view=net-6.0#:~:text=The%20minimum%20valid%20date%20for%20a,SqlDateTime%20structure%20is%20January%201%2C%201753 min date is 1753.

Comment: Per the error, a row ends up somewhere with an `SqlDateTime` that is out of range. Pay *close* attention to the error message; this makes no direct statement about the `DateTime` you're feeding it, so a good idea is to dig deeper and figure out how the result of this function actually ends up used. If we try this directly, `new SqlDateTime(new DateTime(1753, 1, 1))` does not produce an error (in .NET 6, at least), which seems to confirm your `DateTime` is not what ends up getting used, at least not directly.

Comment: yes maybe Jeroen, but for sake I can't access the sql server directlyy in the moment.
`new SqlDateTime(new DateTime(1753, 1, 1))` I tried to return but in my environment SqlDateTime is unknown and it is built in into a program - so I can't just add namespaces.

Comment: The `new SqlDateTime` was just to illustrate the problem. I'm not suggesting you access the SQL Server (the problem is *not* occurring there; your data never hits the server and this is strictly a client-side error), I'm suggesting you look at the code that lies between the code you've posted here, and how it ultimately ends up in the DB, as the problem is almost certainly there somewhere. Take a closer look at the full stack trace of the error, and any of the intermediate layers inbetween.

Comment: For that matter, how have you determined the problem is even *in* the code posted? Does it disappear if you simply remove the date/time as is (ignoring the fact that you may end up with an undesirable `NULL`)? Is it possible the base data already contains out-of-range values, unrelated to your `DateTime.Parse` altogether? For example, is it possible that somehow existing "empty" values of `1753-01-01 00:00` are read somewhere, converted to local time, and then end up being streamed out as `1752-12-31` without your knowledge? A range check in the input argument might help there.

Comment: The input values are all ok. I took a look at them, they are all valid dates or null. The code works as far as it distinguishes between a null value or a non-vull-value, because I see in the result of the synchronisation, that only those with null values fail to update.
The idea to revise the other code is good, but I can't even debug my code, because it is run by the sync program I use. So there is no layer I could have a closer look to or a more detailed error message or a trace. I can't write even to console.

Comment: How are you converting the DateTime to a parameter of the SQL query? Somewhere a correct DateTime value is converted into a wrong one as people have been trying to point out. You  can surely just check your sql command text before it gets executed and just throw an Exception yourself containing the value?

Comment: The support of layer2 made my day! The following works fine:
`if (NächstesFSKontrolldatum > DateTime.Parse("1/1/1753 12:00:00"))
   return NächstesFSKontrolldatum;
return DateTime.Parse("1/1/1753 00:00:00");`

Answer (score 0):

The support of layer2 made my day! The following works fine: `if (NächstesFSKontrolldatum > DateTime.Parse("1/1/1753 12:00:00"))    return NächstesFSKontrolldatum; return DateTime.Parse("1/1/1753 00:00:00");`